Proof of the General Deduction Theorem
Theorem: For all axiom systems $\Sigma$ and all formulas $\varphi, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n$, it holds that:
$
\Sigma, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n \vdash \varphi \iff \Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \ldots \to \psi_n \to \varphi$
Proof:
$\Rightarrow$: We prove by complete induction. Initially, that is, for $n = 1$, it holds: Let $\Sigma, \psi_1 \vdash \varphi$, and by the deduction theorem, it immediately follows that $\Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \varphi$. We now assume for a fixed, but arbitrary, $n$ that if $\Sigma, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n \vdash \varphi$, then $\Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \ldots \to \psi_n \to \varphi$. We can assume $\Sigma, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n, \psi_{n +1}\vdash \varphi$. We define $\Sigma$‘ := $\Sigma, \psi_1, \dots, \psi_n$, thus $\Sigma$‘, $\psi_{n+1} \vdash \varphi$. Then from the Deduction Theorem follows $\Sigma$‘ $\vdash \psi_{n+1} \to \varphi$, i.e. $\Sigma, \psi_1, \dots, \psi_n \vdash \psi_{n+1} \to \varphi$. By induction hypothesis we get $\Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \ldots \to \psi_n \to \psi_{n+1} \to \varphi$, thus proving the Induction hypothesis (by proving the cases n = 1 and n + 1).
$\Leftarrow$: Again, the proof is by complete induction. Initially, that is, for $n = 1$, it holds: $\Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \varphi$, and by the deduction theorem, it immediately follows that $\Sigma, \psi_1 \vdash \varphi$. We now assume for a fixed, but arbitrary, $n$ that if $\Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \ldots \to \psi_n \to \varphi$, then $\Sigma, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n \vdash \varphi$. If now $\Sigma \vdash \psi_1 \to \ldots \to \psi_{n+1} \to \varphi$, then by the induction hypothesis, $\Sigma, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n \vdash \psi_{n+1} \to \varphi$. By a single application of the deduction theorem, we immediately obtain $\Sigma, \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n, \psi_{n+1} \vdash \varphi$, so that the induction hypothesis (by proving the cases $n = 1$ and n+1) is proven.
Questions: I found a solution to my first original question. It is the bold-marked part but is doable as I did?
The deduction theorem is proven by strong induction, this general version of the deduction theorem is proven by complete induction. Why? Here is my try maybe it gives you inside about my understanding:
Unlike the proof of the deduction theorem, here there is always exactly one predecessor case for each $n$, and the structure corresponds to the linear chain of natural numbers. In the case of the deduction theorem, however, each $n$ has at least two predecessor cases, meaning the structure is no longer linear but branches out, resembling a tree diagram. Consequently, the induction hypothesis must hold for all $k < n$ to ensure rigor.

Not an answer to your questions, but notice that the proof can be simplified by a) proving the equivalence directly without proving it as two implications, b) starting the induction with $n=0$.

Looks fine, I agree with Martin that it would be better to just do the equivalence by induction all at once. I think your reasoning at the end makes sense… in the proof of the deduction theorem we need to consider proofs with lengths that could be any number less than $n$, whereas in this case it suffices to assume it works for $n-1$ formulas.

I don't know what "all axiom systems" means here.  It happens many times in the literature that well-formed formulas (axioms) with clear rules of inference appear.  The deduction theorem does not hold for plenty of those systems.
