Proof of Deduction Theorem in Hilbert-Calculus, Beginner friendly
Deduction Theorem:
Let $ \Sigma$ be an axiom system, and let $ \psi, \varphi$ be $ L$-formulas. Then the following always holds:
$
\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi \iff \Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi
$
“$ \Rightarrow$”
We prove by strong induction on the length of a proof $ n \geq 1$ that for arbitrary $ \Sigma, \psi, \varphi$, the following holds: if $ \varphi$ can be proven from $ \Sigma, \psi$ (in the Hilbert calculus) with length $ n$, then $ \psi \rightarrow \varphi$ can also be proven from $ \Sigma$.
Note: This is not standard (complete) induction but its generalization, which works because of the well-ordering of the natural numbers. The difference from standard induction lies in the fact that the induction hypothesis holds not just for one fixed (but arbitrary) $ n$ but for all $ k < n$. Therefore, there is no base case as in standard induction.
Induction Hypothesis: Let $ n$ be arbitrary, and assume that for all proof lengths $ k < n$, if the formula $ \varphi$ can be derived from $ \Sigma, \psi$ via a proof of length $ k$, then there also exists a proof for the formula $ \psi \to \varphi$ from $ \Sigma$.
Induction Step: Let $ \Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi$ via a proof $ \Delta = \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n$ $ \varphi_n = \varphi$. By the definition of a formal proof in the Hilbert calculus, the following cases arise:

$ \varphi$ is a logical axiom. Then, using the logical axiom $ \varphi \implies \psi \implies \varphi$ and modus ponens, $ \psi \implies \varphi$ can be derived without any premises. By the monotonicity property of classical logic calculi, the derivation succeeds from any (non-empty) premise set $ \Sigma$, i.e., $ \Sigma \vDash \psi \implies \varphi$.

$ \varphi \in \Sigma, \{\psi\}$.
2.1. If $ \psi \neq \varphi$, then $ \varphi \in \Sigma$, and modus ponens applied to the logical axiom $ \varphi \implies \psi \implies \varphi$ yields $ \psi \implies \varphi$ from $ \Sigma$, i.e., $ \Sigma \vdash \psi \implies \varphi$.
2.2. If $ \psi = \varphi$, then $ \psi \rightarrow \varphi$ and $ \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ are identical formulas. It suffices to show that $ \Sigma \vdash \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$, proving that $ \Sigma \vdash \psi \to \varphi$. Starting with $ \varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi) \rightarrow \varphi$ as an instance of the first logical axiom, we apply it as the antecedent of the second logical axiom. This yields the formula $ (\varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi) \rightarrow \varphi) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi)) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi)$. Using modus ponens twice, we derive $ \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ solely from logical axioms without additional premises. Therefore, this formula holds for any $ \Sigma$, owing to the monotonicity of classical logic calculi.

$ \varphi$ follows from $ mp$. Then there exist proofs of length $ k, \ell < n$ for $ \varphi_k$ and $ \varphi_\ell = (\varphi_k \implies \varphi)$ from $ \Sigma, \psi$. By the induction hypothesis, $ \Sigma \vdash \psi \implies \varphi_k$ and $ \Sigma \vdash \psi \implies \varphi_\ell = (\varphi_k \implies \varphi)$. Using the logical axiom $ (\varphi \implies \psi \implies \chi) \implies (\varphi \implies \psi) \implies (\varphi \implies \chi)$, and substituting appropriately, we derive $ (\psi \implies \varphi_k \implies \varphi) \implies (\psi \implies \varphi_k)$ $ \implies (\psi \implies \varphi)$. Applying modus ponens twice, we conclude $ \psi \implies \varphi$ from $ \Sigma$, i.e., $ \Sigma \vdash \psi \implies \varphi$.


Thus, for all proofs in the Hilbert calculus (of arbitrary length $ n$), the formula  $
\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi \implies \Sigma \vdash \psi \implies \varphi
$
holds.
“$ \Leftarrow$”
Let $ \Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$, i.e., let $ \Delta = \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n$ be a proof for $ \varphi_n = \psi \rightarrow \varphi$ from $ \Sigma$. By the rules of the Hilbert calculus, we can designate any $ L$-formula as an additional axiom; we take $ \psi$. From $ \psi$ and $ \psi \rightarrow \varphi$, $ \varphi$ follows via $ mp$. Thus, $ \Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi$. $ \square$
This is as good a proof as it gets esp. for beginners and easy to follow. It should be close to flawless. But I wonder if my note as the start of the proof is alright as well or if there are tiny incorrections. Of course if you find anything problematic beyond tiny unimportant things, feel free to jump in and explain.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

How about: Suppose we can infer from P
is true that Q
is true, i.e. it cannot be the case that both P
is true and Q
is false. As a convenient abbreviation, instead of $\neg (P \land \neg Q)$ we can simply write, P⟹Q.

I don't see what purpose the note serves. If you think your audience might be unfamiliar with strong induction, you should take a moment to explain it. If it's safe to assume they are, you shouldn't. This is some middle ground that will confuse the former and annoy the latter. (On a more minor note, you seem to refer to "standard" induction as "complete" induction. In my experience, "complete" is usually a synonym for "strong", but terminology varies.)

@spaceisdarkgreen: The note is for me and I am not familiar with strong induction but I wanted to use the occasion to explain it a little bit without going too far. Is the content of the note ok or is there a glaring mistake?

@spaceisdarkgreen Oh, and do you see anything false or fishy in the proof? It should not but if something jumps at you feel free to tell me.

@God No, nothing you said was mistaken, just thought it was a bit vague if you were actually trying to teach it. I haven't really focused on the fine details in the rest of the proof, but overall it looks correct and complete.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thx. I have a proof of the general deduction theorem here too. Maybe you can have a look and tell me about it since no one seems to care. Just an invitation that is. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5008245/proof-of-the-general-deduction-theorem?noredirect=1#comment10738363_5008245
